# Shrinking JLabels in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, graphics, jlabel

I am writing a ultimate monopoly game and it is  nearly finished.[image]

But in a lot of cases I want a position input from the user so the user needs to learn the number of the squares.But as you can see in the picture I dont ve enough space to write 120 different positions.My question is can I create a window which do not have a fixed size?So user can check that box when he wants to enter a position and shrink it when he/she does not need it.

Comment: it's not clear what you mean, Perhaps you can use a JOptionPane?

Comment: Yes, you can create 2 board sizes.  One that fits on the screen with minimal detail, and one with full detail inside of a JScrollPane.

Comment: Think of a wordpad file.It includes a lot of text and it can be minimized.Thats what I need.Edit:What Gilbert said is what I wanted

Comment: Spending on how you've laid everything out to begin with, you could make use of an Overlay layout manager or the glassPane to overlay the cell numbers

Comment: *Depending* - apparently the iPads autocorrect doesn't like my typing

Answer (score 0):

You can make the label sizes relative and give priority to certain ones, for depending on which row they're on that row is larger, and shrink the other squares based on an offset relative to that.